# Where do I put an extension to open_uri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, open-uri

I'm trying to fetch an image from Twitter:

```
open("http://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image/barackobama.png?size=bigger")
```

But I get:

```
RuntimeError: redirection forbidden: http://... -> https://...
```

There is an [open issue](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/859) and it seems that I can use an [extension to open_uri](https://gist.github.com/zaius/1271420) but I don't know how it works. For example, if I place it in `lib/` or if I paste the module in the console, it still doesn't work. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the proper place to put such a patch is in a file inside `config/initializers`, i.e. `config/initializers/open_uri_allow_unsafe_redirects_patch.rb`. You have to `require 'open-uri'` before reopening the `OpenURI` module:

```
require 'open-uri'    
module OpenURI
  # the rest of the file here...
end
```

Then you have to call `open` passing the option `allow_unsafe_redirects` set to `true`:

```
open('http://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image/barackobama.png?size=bigger',
     allow_unsafe_redirects: true)
```

You can find more informations about initializer files on the Ruby on Rails [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#using-initializer-files)

Comment: Thanks @toro2k, I've tried that but I still get "redirection forbidden".